# How do I publish an easily extendable web service in Java?

Tags: java, web-services

The following question is for a web service I'm working on at my internship:

I need to develop a web service in Java that exposes a constantly evolving number of methods. This web service actually calls another web service that handles all the executions.  The clients that will consume this web service are not necessarily written in Java.

Two methods of the service that will always be there are: `open` and `close`. Another method we'd like to expose in the web service is a `command` method, that takes at least one String (the name of the command to be executed on the remote server that the web service calls) as a parameter. So for example, the client that consumes this service, would be able to invoke `command("save");` and the web service would execute the save command.

Now here's the tricky part: my boss wants me to make it so that each separate command (i.e. save, print, exportToPdf - and a whole lot more) can be invoked directly without having to call the `command` method and passing the name of the command as a String. However, as new commands are added periodically, we'd like to be able to just have a list of these commands (and their parameters) in a text/xml file, and somehow make the web service expose each of these commands as a web method.

I'm not sure if the above is clear. Here's a  (vague) idea of how I think it could be done:

1. Json RPC

> Parse the URL of the HTTP request, and if it ends with `open`, `close` or `command`, then execute those methods. Otherwise, check if it ends with one of the command names in the text/xml file, and if it is, call that method. As an example, if the client tries to consume the web service through `http://myservice/open` or `http://myservice/command`, then those methods will be executed. If they try `http://myservice/othermethod`then the text file is checked, before trying to call the other web service.

1. Jax-WS

> I could expose one web service for the `open`, `close` and `command` methods. Then I could expose a separate web service containing just the one catch-all method which in turn just calls the `command` method and passes the command name and parameters as arguments. This second web service can be made accessible at various URLs (by iterating through the list of commands and caling `Endpoint.publish` with a different URL for each one), so for example, `http://myservice/specialmethod` will invoke this catch-all method, which in turn will call `command("specialmethod")`.

I've reread this question a few times now, and I'm really not sure how clear it is. In case it isn't, here are some simpler questions:

Is there a way to have a catch-all endpoint URL in a web service, such that if this URL is called, a particular method is executed? Is it possible to use wildcard characters in the endpoint URLs?

Comment: Is having the "command" method mandatory?  I suspect you'll end up having to do a lot of maintenance on that method as your API grows.  The other requirements sound like REST, and your biggest problem there will be picking one out of the hundreds of frameworks that provide a REST interface.  The Spring Framework might have what you're looking for.

Comment: What is the user interface? Will they be expected to type in URLs like http://myservice/open in a browser? If you have an HTML page that provides buttons (or whatever) for the commands, the question how the URL and, ultimately, the server side invocation is implemented is rather secondary.

Comment: No, the "command" method is not mandatory, it's just there because that's how the existing web service (that will be consumed by this web service I must create) works. It's like, method invocation by message (I think that's what it's called). I'm not aware of what the user interface is like. Basically this web service I'm writing will be used by developers writing clients but not wanting to call the existing web service because the "command" method is really clunky)

Comment: I've only limited experience with server configuration but I do know that you can do some fancy stuff with server configuration. That would be another way to hide the actual server-side implementation from what is expected as an URL.

Comment: OK, I've gone through forgotten stuff. Apache contains the `RewriteRule`configuration command, which should enable you to convert the last section of an URL to a parameter of an URL ending in command?text=$1.

Comment: Ah, that's really quite different. Didn't occur to me to think of that. Thanks for the suggestion. A quick search based on your idea led me to ths: https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/ 

I'll see if I could use that.